# Show that a square of an integer cannot give the remainder $2$ when divided by $3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Wanted to see if my approach is correct:

Let $x=3k+r$ for integer quotient $k$ and remainder $r$
Then $x^2=9k^2+6kr+r^2$
If $r=2$, then $x^2=9k^2+12k+4=3(3k^2+4k+\frac{2}{3})+2$

$3k^2+4k+\frac{2}{3}$ cannot be an integer, thus the square of an integer cannot give remainder $2$ when divided by $3$

Comment: It's correct but not elegant. Try to use congruence, it will give you an elegant proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine for $r=2$. But you mix "remainder" in the question and "remainder" in the setup of your integer (this is $r$). So this needs to be checked as well for $r = 0$ and $r = 1$.

If $r=0$, then $x^2=9k^2=3(3k^2-\frac{2}{3})+2$
If $r=1$, then $x^2=9k^2+6k+1=3(3k^2+2k-\frac{1}{3})+2$

As $k$ is integer, the terms in parantheses cannot be integers.

So this holds generally.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$x\equiv 0,1,2\mod 3$$ squaring this we obtain: $$x^2\equiv 0,1,2^2\equiv 0,1 \mod 3$$